# can't getting same in child component

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ng-class

should get same result from parent component to child component in angular. ngclass giving not exact result in child component. Need correct format of it.

```
[ngClass]="{
                'card-color': !deviceStatus[element.devID]?.status,
                'cell-danger':
                  element[sensor.sensorId].value <
                    element[sensor.sensorId].min ||
                  element[sensor.sensorId].value >
                    element[sensor.sensorId].max
              }"
```

Comment: Your question is missing details, e.g., how do you enter the data into your child.component, what is not working. Please add more details and code samples to your questions, otherwise we cannot help you

Comment: I'm asking is it correct way of ngclass syntax mentioned above.